# Why is the Suzuki coupling done under inert atmosphere?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, organotransition-metal-chemistry

There are plenty of sources saying that the Suzuki coupling is air-sensitive (even though there are [some versions](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2011/ob/c0ob00524j#!divAbstract) that require oxygen). However I'd like to know why a typical Suzuki coupling is air-sensitive. I cannot find what the oxygen actually does.  Pd(0) doesn't seem like it would get oxidised in air that easily, does it?

Comment: A Suzuki coupling isn't oxidative; it shouldn't require oxygen. What schemes are these? Can you attach them?

Comment: Sure, here https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2011/ob/c0ob00524j#!divAbstract

Comment: However I'm asking about the normal version where it's done under N2 or Ar, I'd like to know why.

Comment: Ah, I now see that perhaps my question was ambiguous.  I will try to amend it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure that the standard one is oxygen-sensitive because Pd(0) is easily oxidised. That oxygen Suzuki is a bit underexplained, there is only [a speculative suggestion in an earlier paper by the authors](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2009/CC/B912364D#!divAbstract)...

Comment: Yes, it is to keep Pd at (0)